# Dimension error building LSTM with keras

Tags: keras, lstm

I am trying to builda LSTM network using Keras.
My time seriese example is of size `492`. And I want to use the `3` previous examples to predict the next example. So, the input is converted to size `(num_samples,3*492)`,and the output size is `(num_samples,492)`.

According to [this blog](https://machinelearningmastery.com/multivariate-time-series-forecasting-lstms-keras/?spm=5176.100239.blogcont174270.18.50ngWN), I firstly convert my data size into of form (num_samples,timesteps,features)

```
#convert trainning data to 3D LSTM shape
train_origin_x = train_origin_x.reshape((train_origin_x.shape[0],3,492))
test_origin_x  = test_origin_x.reshape((test_origin_x.shape[0],3,492))
print(train_origin_x.shape,test_origin_x.shape)
(216, 3, 492) (93, 3, 492)
print(train_origin_y,test_origin_y)
(216, 492) (93, 492)
```

And below is the my code to build the LSTM network

```
#building network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(hidden_units,return_sequences=True,input_shape=(train_origin_x.shape[1],train_origin_x.shape[2])))
model.add(Dense(492))
model.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='adam')
print('model trainning begins...')
history = model.fit(train_origin_x,train_origin_y,epochs = num_epochs,batch_size = num_batchs,
          validation_data=(test_origin_x,test_origin_y))
```

However I got an error in the process, saying

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (216, 492)
```

Anyone knows the what's the problem?

Any comments or suggestions is welcome and appreciated!!

Below is the result of `model.summary()`

```
model.summary()
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 3, 50)             108600    
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 3, 492)            25092     
=================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add return_sequences to your LSTM code:

```
model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequences = False,input_shape=(train_origin_x.shape[1],train_origin_x.shape[2])))
```